# Importing email info to excel

Tags: email, outlook

I am trying to import email information from a sub-folder of a shared inbox in Outlook into an excel spreadsheet. I encountered lots of issues so far, namely accessing the sub-folder of the inbox, but have found solutions. The problem I now have is the code stopping after the same number of emails that are present in the Inbox. For example, I am trying to get information from the "Archive" folder (a sub-folder of the Inbox) but if there are 20 emails in my Inbox, then the code stops when the count reaches 20 and only gives me the information for 20 items in the "Archive" folder

See my code below executed from Outlook. I have marked where the code stops. It gives me the error "aOutput(lCnt, 1) = Subscript out of range" when I hoover the cursor over "aOutput". If I skip the code to the "SetxlApp..." line it will give me the excel sheet populated with data for all emails up to that point (20 emails i.e. the same number of items in my Inbox) but I need it to keep looping through the rest of the folder (could be thousands of items). Could anyone shed any light on this please? Any other suggestions? Thanks for your help.

```
Sub EmailStats()

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim aOutput() As Variant
Dim lCnt As Long
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlSh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim flInbox As Folder
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Team Inbox")

Set flInbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderInbox)

Set olFolder = flInbox.Folders("ARCHIVE")
ReDim aOutput(1 To flInbox.Items.Count, 1 To 4)

For Each olMail In olFolder.Items
    If TypeName(olMail) = "MailItem" Then
    On Error GoTo ErrorSkip
        lCnt = lCnt + 1
        aOutput(lCnt, 1) = olMail.SenderEmailAddress '**Code stops here**
        aOutput(lCnt, 2) = olMail.ReceivedTime
        aOutput(lCnt, 3) = olMail.ConversationTopic
        aOutput(lCnt, 4) = olMail.Subject
    End If
ErrorSkip:
Next olMail

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set xlSh = xlApp.Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)

xlSh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(aOutput, 1), UBound(aOutput, 2)).Value = aOutput
xlApp.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `On Error GoTo ErrorSkip` line and see what (if any) error is returned.

Comment: I get the same error when I remove the 'On Error GoTo ErrorSkip' line. I only input this to try and fix the initial problem but it does nothing.

Comment: You never initialize the lCnt variable. Initialize it to 0 before entering the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry if I am not too familiar with Outlook VBA but I tried inputting lCnt = 0 before the loop starts but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after much trial and error. For anyone who is interested see below code to import email details from a shared inbox into an excel sheet. Just change the "Shared Inbox" text to the name of your own shared inbox. My inbox is structured as "Shared Inbox" > "Inbox" > "ARCHIVE". You would also need to change these on the Set objFolder line to specify the folder you need.

I still have one issue where the code stops when it meets a non-mail item (a non-delivery notification or meeting invite) but am working on a solution.

```
Sub EmailStatsV3()

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim aOutput() As Variant
Dim lCnt As Long
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlSh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim flInbox As Folder

'Gets the mailbox and shared folder inbox
Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Shared Inbox")

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objInbox = objNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderInbox)

'Uses the Parent of the Inbox to specify the mailbox
strFolderName = objInbox.Parent

'Specifies the folder (inbox or other) to pull the info from
Set objMailbox = objNamespace.Folders(strFolderName)
Set objFolder = objMailbox.Folders("Inbox").Folders("ARCHIVE")
Set colItems = objFolder.Items

'Specify which email items to extract
ReDim aOutput(1 To objFolder.Items.Count, 1 To 5)
For Each olMail In objFolder.Items
If TypeName(olMail) = "MailItem" Then

        lCnt = lCnt + 1
        aOutput(lCnt, 1) = olMail.SenderEmailAddress 'maybe stats on domain
        aOutput(lCnt, 2) = olMail.ReceivedTime 'stats on when received
        aOutput(lCnt, 3) = olMail.ConversationTopic 'group based on subject w/o regard to prefix
        aOutput(lCnt, 4) = olMail.Subject 'to split out prefix
        aOutput(lCnt, 5) = olMail.Categories 'to split out category
End If

Next

'Creates a blank workbook in excel then inputs the info from Outlook
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set xlSh = xlApp.Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)

xlSh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(aOutput, 1), UBound(aOutput, 2)).Value = aOutput
xlApp.Visible = True


End Sub
```